# How to use Typescript with Angular CLI and Express/Node in the same project?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, typescript, angular-cli

I am building a skeleton MEAN project using the Angular CLI. Here is a look at the folder structure and the tsconfig.json file.

[image]

Right now, the server code, in the server directory, is written in JavaScript and I would like to be able to write it in TypeScript.

In development, I usually run the following commands:

```
nodemon server.js
ng build --watch
```

I am wondering what changes do I need to make in order to be able to write my server code in TypeScript? Do I need to create a separate tsconfig.json file somewhere else to deal with the server code or can instructions for Angular and server code be contained in the same tsconfig.json file? Can I keep using the 2 above commands for my development? Do I need to add a new command? Ideally, I would prefer a solution that doesn't use tools like Gulp but sticks to NPM scripts, if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution. I have added a second tsconfig file in the root directory that I named tsconfig-server.json. Here is a look at the content of this file:

[image]

What's more, I have changed my NPM start script to run the following:

```
"start": "ng build -watch | tsc -p tsconfig-server.json -watch | nodemon server.js"
```

Comment: Have you found a better solution, as I'm experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Nah, that's the solution I'm using; a separate config file for the server code.

Comment: can i get your repo i am near to run both on single